# What school computer should I buy?

Tags: processor, memory, data-storage, battery-life

I'm a recent graduate from high school. I want to make sure I'm prepared to enter college as a computer science major. However, I don't have a computer. I don't know which computer to get for college. I want to make sure, with the limited money that I have, that I will buy a computer that will be able to do whatever I need to for my computer science classes. I'm also interested in specializing in cybersecurity. Therefore, my computer should also be able to run programs as necessary. Please help steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you please describe in question activities, programs you want/need to run. Also some idea/requirement about the OS may be helpful.

Comment: For these use cases I think one with a bunch of RAM and Kali Linux is gonna be best for you, although I don't know of any laptops that have that out-of-the-box. You can maybe try the Framework one

Answer (score 0):

Desktop:

- CPU: i5 latest generation or equivalent
- RAM: 16 GB
- HDD: NVMe + small HDD + free cloud storage
- Graphic card: basic / integrated
- OS: Linux

Laptop:

- CPU: i3 latest generation or equivalent
- RAM: 8 GB
- HDD: small
- Graphic card: integrated cheap one
- OS: Linux

Don't forget each day you take your laptop to college it won't necessarily come back home (left back, stolen...) so an expensive one (>600€) is not a good idea

Comment: 8GB of RAM really isn’t much, and seeing as this laptop will probably be used for years I’d suggest getting at least 16GB